# Trackballcontrols and gui can't work together

Tags: javascript, three.js

The gui change together when I click on them and I've seen other answer, but don't know where should I put the listener, I've tried to put the listener in render(), but still don't so how can I fix my code? This coding relates to my graduation.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>map draw</title>
  <!-- Original:
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../build/three.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/js/libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="../examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
          -->
  <!-- Added by TheJim01 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
  <!-- End TheJim01 additions -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Stats-output"></div>
  <div id="camera"></div>
  <div id="airport"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var controls = new Array(cube_number);
      console.log(controls);
      var cubes = new Array(cube_number);
      var guicube = new Array(cube_number);
      var cube_number = 4; //change this word,you can change the number of cubes
      var stats = initStats()
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position.x = 10;
      camera.position.y = 10;
      camera.position.z = 30;
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera); //配置控制器
      var clock = new THREE.Clock();
      trackballControls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
      trackballControls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
      trackballControls.panSpeed = 1.0;
      trackballControls.domElement = document.querySelector('#camera')
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000)); //背景颜色设置
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(60);
      scene.add(axes);
      for (var i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
        controls[i] = new function() {
          this.PositionX = 0;
          this.PositionY = 0;
          this.PositionZ = 0;
          this.ScaleX = 1;
          this.ScaleY = 1;
          this.ScaleZ = 1;
          this.RotationX = 0;
          this.RotationY = 0;
          this.RotationZ = 0;
        }
      }
      var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(65, 65);
      var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x808080
      });
      var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
      plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
      plane.position.x = 0;
      plane.position.y = 0;
      plane.position.z = 0;
      scene.add(plane);
      for (var i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6, 6, 6);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF,
          wireframe: false
        });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.position.x = 2 * i;
        cube.position.y = 0;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        cube.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        cube.name = "cube-" + i;
        scene.add(cube);
      }
      //render the scene
      render();
      document.getElementById("airport").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      function render() {
        for (i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
          stats.update();
          cubes[i] = scene.getObjectByName("cube-" + i);
          cubes[i].position.x = controls[i].PositionX;
          cubes[i].position.y = controls[i].PositionY;
          cubes[i].position.z = controls[i].PositionZ;
          cubes[i].scale.set(controls[i].ScaleX, controls[i].ScaleY, controls[i].ScaleZ);
          cubes[i].rotation.x = controls[i].RotationX;
          cubes[i].rotation.y = controls[i].RotationY;
          cubes[i].rotation.z = controls[i].RotationZ;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        var delta = clock.getDelta();
        trackballControls.update(delta);
      }
      //here is the biggest problem
      var gui = new dat.GUI();
      for (i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
        guicube[i] = gui.addFolder(cubes[i].name);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'PositionX', -20, 20);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'PositionY', -8, 40);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'PositionZ', -20, 20);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'ScaleX', 1, 8);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'ScaleY', 1, 8);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'ScaleZ', 1, 8);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'RotationX', -4, 4);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'RotationY', -4, 4);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'RotationZ', -4, 4);
      }
    }

    function initStats() {
      var stats = new Stats();
      stats.setMode(0);
      stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
      stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
      document.getElementById("Stats-output").appendChild(stats.domElement);
      return stats;
    }
    window.onload = init();
  </script>
  //改动cube_number参数，可以改变添加立方体的个数
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a moment to read [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I understand English may not be your first language, but please try to clarify your question. If you can answer these questions, we can help answer yours: **1.** What problem are you experiencing? **2.** Are you seeing any errors in the console? **3.** What have you tried to resolve the problem/errors?

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind, since you mentioned it, make sure you are aware of the rules and repercussions of using the work of others in your school project. Some places may consider copying a solution from a site like StackOverflow as academic dishonesty, which can lead to disciplinary measures as extreme as expulsion. I'm not saying this is the case for you. I'm just saying be aware, and be careful.

Comment: Thank you very much,i will remeber you advise and I will try to explain my question better next time.I am very appreciate for your advise.sorry for my terrible English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the domElement of `trackballControls` in the wrong place. It has to be passed as the second parameter of the constructor. Additionally, make sure you're passing the same domElement as the `renderer` so you won't run into z-indexing issues.

**Wrong**

```
var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
trackballControls.domElement = document.querySelector('#camera'); // too late to declare here
...
document.getElementById("airport").appendChild(renderer.domElement); // Will lead to stacking issues
```

---

**Correct:**

```
var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, document.querySelector('#airport'));
...
document.getElementById("airport").appendChild(renderer.domElement); // Same element as trackball
```

**Additionally**

Make sure you're calling `stats.update();` outside the `for()` loop, otherwise it'll run 4 times per frame, leading to an incorrect 240 FPS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>map draw</title>
  <!-- Added by TheJim01 -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
  <!-- End TheJim01 additions -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Stats-output"></div>
  <div id="airport"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var controls = new Array(cube_number);
      console.log(controls);
      var cubes = new Array(cube_number);
      var guicube = new Array(cube_number);
      var cube_number = 4; //change this word,you can change the number of cubes
      var stats = initStats()
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position.x = 10;
      camera.position.y = 10;
      camera.position.z = 30;
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, document.querySelector('#airport')); // pass the #airport DIV as its second parameter.
      var clock = new THREE.Clock();
      trackballControls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
      trackballControls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
      trackballControls.panSpeed = 1.0;
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000)); //背景颜色设置
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(60);
      scene.add(axes);
      for (var i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
        controls[i] = new function() {
          this.PositionX = 0;
          this.PositionY = 0;
          this.PositionZ = 0;
          this.ScaleX = 1;
          this.ScaleY = 1;
          this.ScaleZ = 1;
          this.RotationX = 0;
          this.RotationY = 0;
          this.RotationZ = 0;
        }
      }
      var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(65, 65);
      var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x808080
      });
      var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
      plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
      plane.position.x = 0;
      plane.position.y = 0;
      plane.position.z = 0;
      scene.add(plane);
      for (var i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(6, 6, 6);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          color: Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF,
          wireframe: false
        });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.position.x = 2 * i;
        cube.position.y = 0;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        cube.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
        cube.name = "cube-" + i;
        scene.add(cube);
      }
      //render the scene
      render();
      document.getElementById("airport").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      function render() {
        stats.update();
        for (i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
          cubes[i] = scene.getObjectByName("cube-" + i);
          cubes[i].position.x = controls[i].PositionX;
          cubes[i].position.y = controls[i].PositionY;
          cubes[i].position.z = controls[i].PositionZ;
          cubes[i].scale.set(controls[i].ScaleX, controls[i].ScaleY, controls[i].ScaleZ);
          cubes[i].rotation.x = controls[i].RotationX;
          cubes[i].rotation.y = controls[i].RotationY;
          cubes[i].rotation.z = controls[i].RotationZ;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        var delta = clock.getDelta();
        trackballControls.update(delta);
      }
      //here is the biggest problem
      var gui = new dat.GUI();
      for (i = 0; i < cube_number; i++) {
        guicube[i] = gui.addFolder(cubes[i].name);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'PositionX', -20, 20);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'PositionY', -8, 40);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'PositionZ', -20, 20);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'ScaleX', 1, 8);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'ScaleY', 1, 8);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'ScaleZ', 1, 8);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'RotationX', -4, 4);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'RotationY', -4, 4);
        guicube[i].add(controls[i], 'RotationZ', -4, 4);
      }
    }

    function initStats() {
      var stats = new Stats();
      stats.setMode(0);
      stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
      stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
      document.getElementById("Stats-output").appendChild(stats.domElement);
      return stats;
    }
    window.onload = init();
  </script>
  //改动cube_number参数，可以改变添加立方体的个数
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,it works.You mean i have to point the ID ,or the trackballcontrols can't find my camera.But after fixing,i found another problem:"the drag events didn't work".The tracksball didn't work perfect.If you know the reason,please tell me.If you don't know,no matter,I will try to fix it myself.

Comment: It's not a big problem,but i want to make the perfect.

Comment: Hmm... do drag events not work on my code sample? I remember testing my code snippet on my computer, and both drag and GUI controls worked well.

Comment: I mead variation "panSpeed" didn't work.More simple saying is I can't using my Right Mouse to drag such as"WASD".If you can,maybe my Mouse has some problem,HaHa.I am appreciate for your help as a newcomer.So if you don't know why,just pass it.